# Active Directory Synchronize automation Deep security

Tags: deepsecurity

We are currently installing deep security using ansible on our computers.
To automate everything without any human interaction, some parts of the configuration are made by SQL injection, even if it's not recommended by Trend Micro (have to deal with what the previous team did :))
all works great, but something is still missing : The sync with active directory user that will create a scheduled task every 24 hours at the same time.

I was wondering which solution could i find (SQL/powershell/bash etc...) to automate this AD sync and activate the scheduled task automatically?

Already checked the automation guide from deep security without success.